# ActiveRecord count distinct when joining tables

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to create an ActiveRecord query that counts all the `events` where the `position = move_left` for a particular user, joined onto `statuses` when the `status` is either `moved` or `moved_correct`. The problem I'm struggling with is that my `events` may have more than one record with the same data for a specific user, since they are events and you're able to perform the same event more than once.

My two models:

Event:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :status
```

Status:

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :events
```

Since there's multiple users, I need to get the last created `event` for each specific user, and join onto `statuses` where the `statuses.position` is `moved` or `moved_correct`.

```
SELECT  `events`.* FROM `events` ORDER BY `events`.`id` DESC

=> <Event id: 1, user_id: 1, position: "move_left">
=> <Event id: 2, user_id: 1, position: "right">
=> <Event id: 3, user_id: 1, position: "move_left">

=> <Event id: 4, user_id: 2, position: "move_left">
=> <Event id: 5, user_id: 2, position: "right">
=> <Event id: 6, user_id: 3, position: "right">
```

..

```
SELECT  `statuses`.* FROM `statuses` ORDER BY `statuses`.`id` DESC

=> <Status id: 1, status_now: "moved", user_id: 1>
=> <Status id: 2, status_now: "moved_correct", user_id: 1>

=> <Status id: 3, status_now: "moved", user_id: 2>
=> <Status id: 4, status_now: "moved_correct", user_id: 3>
=> <Status id: 5, status_now: "moved_down", user_id: 3>
```

With that sample data, the total number I would expect to see would be 4 (`user_id: 1` returns 2, `user_id: 2` returns 1, `user_id: 3` returns 1)

This is an example query of how I pictured it, but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Event.select(:user_id).distinct.order(id: :desc).first.joins("JOIN statuses ON events.user_id = statuses.user_id AND 
statuses.status_now IN ('moved', 'moved_correct')").count
```

Answer (score 0):

According to my assumption of your given scenario try this:

```
Event.joins(:user).joins(:status)
.where("statuses.status_now IN ('moved', 'moved_correct') AND events.position = 'move_left')"
.distinct.count("events.id")
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working correctly. To clarify I'm looking for something more like: SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(DISTINCT statuses.id) FROM `events` INNER JOIN `statuses` ON `statuses`.`user_id` = `activity_events`.`user_id` WHERE (statuses.status_now IN ('moved', 'moved_correct') AND events.position = 'move_left') - but with a count of `statuses` based on the last unique `events.user_id`